# Windows powershell file process duplication

Tags: powershell

My folder structure is "C:\Temp\SalesOrder\20160809\cc.txt" when its looking for all the files that need to be processed as soon as the recursion gets to folder "C:\Temp\SalesOrder" & "C:\Temp\SalesOrder\20160809" its processing cc.txt file. How do I rewrite the gci to not to traverse subfolders and only process files "C:\Temp\SalesOrder\20160809"

```
    $flatFilePath = "C:\Temp\Email.csv"
$flatFile = Import-Csv -Path $flatFilePath -Header Dir,Email
$emailID = @{}
foreach ($record in $flatFile) { $emailID[$record.Dir]=$record.Email }

# organization folder
$orgFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\" -Recurse -Exclude *.*

# Send email
foreach ($dir in $orgFolder) {
    $processedfiles = $null
    $emailTo = $null

    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName -Recurse -Include *.txt,*.xls,*.csv,*.xlsx |  ? { $_.FullName } |  
        Foreach-Object { 
           [string]$internalOrg = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$_.Directory.Name
           $processedfiles += [string][System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_.FullName) + " | ";  
        }

    $emailTo = $emailID.Get_Item($dir.Name) -split ";"   

    if ($processedfiles) { Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body "$Body $processedfiles" -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort } 

}
```

Problem area:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName -Recurse -Include *.txt,*.xls,*.csv,*.xlsx |  ? { $_.FullName } |  
        Foreach-Object { 
           [string]$internalOrg = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$_.Directory.Name
           $processedfiles += [string][System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_.FullName) + " | ";  
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about exactly what files you are trying to get with gci?  For example, are you only trying to get folder names? Any file that isn't cc.txt? Any file that isn't in the same folder as cc.txt?

Comment: I am trying to get all the folders which contains these files "*.txt,*.xls,*.csv,*.xlsx". For instance "C:\Temp\" has subfolders "folder_a", "folder_b", "folder_c", "folder_d", "folder_e"; and only subfolders "folder_a", "folder_e" have files that match the criteria I need just these "C:\Temp\folder_a" & "C:\Temp\folder_e".

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to only select Folders which have the date structure

```
$orgFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\' -Recurse -Exclude *.*
$orgfolder = $orgfolder -match '(\\(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}))'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you have the right code with a small bug. 
In your loop...

```
    Foreach-Object { 
       [string]$internalOrg = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$_.Directory.Name
       $processedfiles += [string][System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_.FullName) + " | ";  
    }
```

... you concatenate the file names, instead of the $internalOrg variables, where you extracted the folder name.

It should be the following if you want the **folders**:

```
    Foreach-Object { 
       [string]$internalOrg = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$_.Directory.Name
       $processedfiles += [string][System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($internalOrg) + " | ";  
    }
```